# Using RegEx to find number followed by dot

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find the index of the reference in a list of references. Let me illustrate:

This is a list of references I scraped off a website:

```
ref = "<p class="references" style="font-size:15px">1. Mcminn. (2003). Last's Anatomy. Elsevier Australia. ISBN:0729537528. <a href="http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN0729537528">Read it at Google Books</a> - <a href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0729537528">Find it at Amazon</a><br>
2. Netter, F. H. (2019). Atlas of human anatomy. Philadelphia, PA: Elsevier.</p>"
```

I thought I could get the index of reference (i.e. "1." and "2.") by using this:

```
result = list(map(int, [e for e in re.split("[^0-9]", ref) if e != '']))
```

But I'm getting all numbers: `[1, 2003, 729537528, 2, 2019]`

How do I only get the list of reference index, i.e. `[1, 2]` One way I guess is to find numbers followed by a dot, but I don't know how.

Comment: Try `result = list(map(int, re.findall(r"([0-9]+)\. ", p.text)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
list(map(int, re.findall(r"(?<![^\s>])([0-9]+)\. ", ref)))
```

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/NZJEDZ):

```
import re
p_text="""ref = <p class="references" style="font-size:15px">1. Mcminn. (2003). Last's Anatomy. Elsevier Australia. ISBN:0729537528. <a href="http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN0729537528">Read it at Google Books</a> - <a href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0729537528">Find it at Amazon</a><br>
2. Netter, F. H. (2019). Atlas of human anatomy. Philadelphia, PA: Elsevier.</p>"""
result = list(map(int, re.findall(r"(?<![^\s>])([0-9]+)\. ", p_text)))
print(result) # => [1, 2]
```

**Details**

- `(?<![^\s>])` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, there is a char other than whitespace and `>`
- `([0-9]+)` - Group 1: one or more digits (it will be the output value from `re.findall`)
- `.`  - a `.` and a space (replace the regular space with `\s` to match any whitespace).

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/QJPGtN/1).

Comment: Thanks for that! I made a mistake using 'p.text' instead of 'ref' as the variable. I corrected it above.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
o = re.findall(r'[>|\s](\d{1})\.', ref)
print(o)
```

Will output:

```
['1', '2']
```

You might need to define a bit more structure, because just number (digit captured by \d) and dot will also capture '8.' at the end of the ISBN number: ISBN:0729537528. Here I used a few characters that (in this example) help distinguishing the two cases. One reference is preceded by a '>' the other one by a space (\s).

Answer (score 0):

You have to "escape" the period so something like "[0-9]*\." should work. That's off the top of my head so it may be slightly wrong; I'll also leave it up to you to figure out why * is there.

Be aware that Regex expressions in Python are slightly different from other implementations.  For definitive info see:

See : https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

which suggests that you should start here:

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#regex-howto

Here's the relevant section of the library page (about 1/ 3 the way down):

The special sequences consist of '\' and a character from the list below. If the ordinary character is not an ASCII digit or an ASCII letter, then the resulting RE will match the second character. For example, \$ matches the character '$'.

For the eqivalent python 2.x page change the version selector found at the top left corner of the page.